# Remove special characters from string on insert?

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, insert, strip

I have a field of type character varying. On insert I'd like to strip out special characters. In this particular case I'd like to strip out hyphens from a column of  hyphenated strings, `hyphen_field`"123-456-789" from `table_two` and insert as "123456789" into `non_hyphen_field` in `table_one`. I'm starting with a statement of the following form:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table_one(var_one,var_two,non_hyphen_field)
SELECT var_one, var_two, hyphen_field
FROM schema.table_two;
```

What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Postgres you can use [replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html) function.

> ```
> select replace('123-456-789', '-','');
> ```
>
> ```
> | replace   |
> | :-------- |
> | 123456789 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8a778f0b449eff96b7636b8692ab6fbc)*